# Getting undefined error while parsing JSON respose for AJAX request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am making an AJAX request to my GPS server, which returns the following JSON format in case of success,

```
{"result":[{"longitude":76.391529,"latitude":27.974347,"location":"Delhi-Ajmer Expressway - Madhosinghpura- Alwar - Rajasthan - India","speed":0,"dttime":"14 Feb 2016 00:38:47","ignition":0,"vehicle_name":"ABCD","icon":0}]}
```

and in case of failure :

```
{"result":[{"error" : "Vehicle location did not found" }]}
```

This is my code :

```
ajaxURL = "http://www.vehicletrack.biz/api/vehlastlocation?token=K2ZFKFMP3A&vehname="+vehicleNum;

//start ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxURL,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[0].longitude);
    }
});
```

Firstly, I want to handle the error case and if result is proper then I want to display each field. Can anyone please help me with accessing the elements of JSON response and handle the error case.

PS : This is my first time with JSON and googling didn'r return relevant JSON format example. Hit and Trial didn't help.

Comment: Based on what you've posted, wouldn't it be `data.result[0].longitude`

Comment: Don't you need a `$.parseJSON(data);` inside your success handler?

Comment: To simplify your work open chrome developer tools and in console put: var result = {"result":[{"error" : "Vehicle location did not found" }]}
then press enter
then put result and press enter again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `dataType` to `json`

```
//start ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxURL,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var json = data.result[0].longitude;
        alert(json);
    }, error: function(data) {
        var err = data.result[0].error;
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle error case like following.

```
success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if(data.result[0].error){
        // error
        alert('Error'); 
    } else {
        // access all properties using loop

        var obj = data.result[0];
        for (var prop in obj ) {
            var propValue = obj[prop];  // access property like this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get `data.result` is undefined.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse`. You can also try `dataType: "json"`. See updated answer.  @InsaneCoder

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to return your result data as json, and treating your result as an object.  However, the datatype specified in your ajax call is text.  I have never used 'text' as a dataType, but I am pretty sure that won't work.  Try `dataType:'json'` instead if you want to process / parse the result into an object from json.

given that, you would want something like:

```
    //start ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxURL,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          var str = 'result ';
          var a = data.result;
          for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++)
          {
          foreach (prop in item)
          {
             // do stuff
             str += ' ' + prop;

          }
          }
          alert( str );
        }
    });
```

One problem you can run into here is using a cross domain requests (the domain you  are sending in your ajax call is not the same as the one your web page is located).  If that is the case, you have to do some special handling on the server and use the `jsonp` data type.  You can get details [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) .

Hope this is what you are looking for.